# Once I marked my project to work as unsafe code I'm getting 10 errors. Why is that?

Tags: c#

I added some CS classes files to my project (*Existing Items*). One of them was with this code inside:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 2)]
        public unsafe struct prDeviceInfoTable{
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 512)]
            public string           DeviceInternalName;         /* Internal device name (512 characters) */
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            public string           ModelName;                  /* Camera model name (32 characters) */
            public UInt16           Generation;                 /* Camera generation number */
            public UInt32           Reserved1;                  /* Reserved */
            public UInt32           ModelID;                    /* Camera model ID */
            public UInt16           Reserved2;                  /* Reserved */
            public UInt16           PortType;                   /* Port type 0x01FWIA / 0x02FSTI */
            public UInt32           Reserved3;                  /* Reserved */
        };
```

So in my project properties I changed it to *Unsafe*. Now I'm getting 10 errors in the file `Assemblyinfo.cs` on these lines:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("CameraSDK Interface")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Used to interface with the Canon SDK")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("LogicRAD")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("CameraSDK")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2006")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
```

The first error for example is:

> Error 1   Duplicate 'AssemblyTitle' attribute

I have downloaded the sample and the CS files from *[A wrapper for the canon CDSDK and PRSDK for remote capture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17344/A-wrapper-for-the-canon-CDSDK-and-PRSDK-for-remote)*.

I used the cannonSDK example after downloaded the sample. And added all the CS files from there, including the `Assemlyinfo.cs` file.

Comment: I'd say you've defined the `AssemblyTitle` attribute multiple times within your assembly.

Comment: The error message says that there is more than one `AssemblyTitle` attribute. Maybe you have more than one AssemblyInfo.cs file in your project? The error is not related to unsafe code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a full project search for "AssemblyTitle". You will probably find multiple occurrences. Perhaps you are even having a duplicate file inside your project. Remove the duplicates (or the file, or the attributes).

Answer (score 0):

For any with this problem check if you included in your project an folder that is an project too.